# Vue.js reuse form validation rules

Tags: forms, validation, vue.js, rules, reusability

I feel that I'm duplicating a lot of code with my forms.

Every form component has this structure:

`template`

```
            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                <v-text-field
                        name="name"
                        v-model="user.name"
                        :rules='nameRules'
                        :label="$t('fields.name')"
                        color="elegant"
                        :error="!!errors.name"
                        :error-messages="errors.name ? errors.name : null"
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                <v-text-field
                        name="surname1"
                        v-model="user.surname1"
                        :rules='surname1Rules'
                        :label="$t('fields.surname1')"
                        color="elegant"
                        :error="!!errors.surname1"
                        :error-messages="errors.surname1 ? errors.surname1 : null"
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                <v-text-field
                        name="surname2"
                        v-model="user.surname2"
                        :rules='surname2Rules'
                        :label="$t('fields.surname2')"
                        color="elegant"
                        :error="!!errors.surname2"
                        :error-messages="errors.surname2 ? errors.surname2 : null"
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                <v-text-field
                        name="email"
                        v-model="user.email"
                        :rules='emailRules'
                        :label="$t('fields.email')"
                        color="elegant"
                        :error="!!errors.email"
                        :error-messages="errors.email ? errors.email : null"
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
```

`script`

```
    data() {
        return {
            nameRules: [
                v => !!v || this.$i18n.translate('validation.required', {'attribute': ''}),
                v => (v && v.length <= 100) || this.$i18n.translate('validation.lt.string', {
                    'attribute': '',
                    'value': 100
                }),
            ],
            surname1Rules: [
                v => !!v || this.$i18n.translate('validation.required', {'attribute': ''}),
                v => (v && v.length <= 100) || this.$i18n.translate('validation.lt.string', {
                    'attribute': '',
                    'value': 100
                }),
            ],
            surname2Rules: [
                v => (!v || v.length <= 100) || this.$i18n.translate('validation.lt.string', {
                    'attribute': '',
                    'value': 100
                }),
            ],
            emailRules: [
                v => !!v || this.$i18n.translate('validation.required', {'attribute': ''}),
                v => (v && v.length <= 100) || this.$i18n.translate('validation.lt.string', {
                    'attribute': '',
                    'value': 100
                }),
                v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || this.$i18n.translate('validation.email', {'attribute': ''}),
            ],
```

I'm okay with the template, I have no choice but to write all the fields I need.
But on the script, the rules are being duplicated on other components.

For example the email field, it will always have the same rules: (required, max:100, must be an email).

So it can be a way to define all the rules separately and use them on specific components? Like importing?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed” into the component’s own options.

`src/mixins/validationRules.js`

```
export const validationRules = {
    data() {
        return {
            validationRules_name: [
                v => !!v || this.$i18n.translate('validation.required', {'attribute': ''}),
                v => (v && v.length <= 100) || this.$i18n.translate('validation.lt.string', {
                        'attribute': '',
                        'value': 100
                })
            ],
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Add the mixin to your form components:

```
<template>
    <v-text-field
        :rules="validationRules_name"
    />
</template>

<script>
import { validationRules } from '@/mixins/validationRules'
export default {
    mixins: [validationRules],
    //...
}
</script>
```